# PL/PGSQL trigger how to detect if a column is provided in the SQL statement on UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm writing a PLPGSQL trigger in Postgres and I want to detect if a column is provided in the update statement. I have a userId which I want to use to track changes. the issue is that if the user_id is already in the record that I want to update and the UPDATE SQL doesn't provide the user_id the old user_id is used. I want to detect if the request doesn't provide an user_id on the update to raise an exception.
Is this achievable in the trigger or do I need to make sure to always add the user_id in all the requests?

For example, this should throw an exception:

`UPDATE table SET field1 = 'test' WHERE id=1`

This should run the trigger completely because user ID is in the update:

`UPDATE table SET field1 = 'test',user_id = 2 WHERE id=1`

I am implementing an audit and want to be sure that the user_id is always part of the request.

Thanks

Comment: Please post sample input and output data that you are expecting.

Comment: for example:  this should throw an exception 
`UPDATE table SET field1 = 'test' WHERE id=1`

this should run the trigger completely because user ID is in the update
`UPDATE table SET field1 = 'test'`,user_id = 2 WHERE id=1`

I am implementing an audit and want to be sure that the user_id is always part of the request.

Comment: What about the case where the `user_id` is provided but it is the same as the existing? The issue is that in Postgres an `UPDATE` is a `DELETE`/`INSERT`. This means in a trigger function the `NEW` and `OLD` 'tables' will have all the column values. So it from its point of view `user_id` is always there. The best you can do is see if it's value has changed. For more info see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). You might want to look at user information available [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) and map to `user_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write two `AFTER UPDATE` triggers:

- an `AFTER UPDATE OF (user_id)` trigger called `trigger1` that only contains `RETURN NULL`
- an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger called `trigger2` that unconditionally throws an error

Then the triggers will be executed in that order, because `trigger1` is alphabetically before `trigger2`.

If `user_id` was in the `SET` list, `trigger1` will execute and terminate processing because it returns NULL, so that `trigger2` won't run and no error is thrown.

If `user_id` is not in the `SET` lust, `trigger1` won't run and `trigger2` will throw an error.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) for an explanation of trigger execution order.

Comment: Very clever, I like that! Though I suggest to add a citation of the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) on the the order of trigger execution: "If more than one trigger is defined for the same event on the same relation, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name."

Answer (score 0):

Another (easier?) solution, would be to check if the name of the column exists in the UPDATE statement:

```
IF (current_query() !~ 'user_id') THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'The user_id field is missing!';
END IF;
```

Links to docs:

[current_query()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE)

[POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)